# How to change Angular2 interpolatioin syntax curly brackets to something else?

Tags: angular

I want to use Angular2 with Django, but they both use double curly brackets in templates, is there a way to change them to something else in Angular2 or in Django (found only a way for Jinja2 templating engine, but not Django templating engine) if that's not possible in Angular2?

A link to the official documentation would be really appreciated (wierd, but I couldn't find anything about it there)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use `interporlation` [decorator property](https://angular.io/api/core/Component#interpolation):

```
@Component({
    interpolation: ['start', 'end'],
```

So it can be used like this:

```
@Component({
    interpolation: ['?', '%'],
    template: `<span>?name%</span>
    ...
})
export class AppComponent {
    name: string = 'g';
```

Answer (score 0):

In the component decorator

```
@Component({
    selector: "..",
    templateUrl: "....",
    ...,
   interpolation: [":!", "!:"],
})
```

**[Docs](https://angular.io/api/core/Component#interpolation)**

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/LS5VRDWXmsVThEhAs1jg?p=preview)**